# Pandas ExcelWriter set_column fails to format numbers after DataFrame.to_excel used

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have tried the example code found on the xlsxwriter webpage at http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_pandas_column_formats.html

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':    [1010, 2020, 3030, 2020, 1515, 3030, 4545],
                   'Percentage': [.1,   .2,   .33,  .25,  .5,   .75,  .45 ],
})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add some cell formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

# Note: It isn't possible to format any cells that already have a format such
# as the index or headers or any cells that contain dates or datetimes.

# Set the column width and format.
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)

# Set the format but not the column width.
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format2)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

However it does not format the columns as expected - they simply appear unformatted (no numeric rounding, percentages.)

I am using Pandas 0.15.2. Any ideas. Has this changed recently in Pandas perhaps?

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Seems like this is fixed in Pandas 16. See https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/204

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it is fixed in Pandas 16. See https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/204